# Firefox Crash when the jquery dialog closes

Tags: jquery-ui, firefox, crash

this code is working on firefox and ie

```
var j$dialog = j$('<div><embed width="100%" height="80%" name="plugin" src="'+url+'" type="application/pdf"></div>');
                    j$dialog.dialog({ 
                            modal: true,
                            width: 900,
                            height: 600,
                            draggble: false,
                            position: 'top' ,
                            closeOnEscape: false,
                            buttons: { 
                                Done: function() {
                                        j$("#translist").html('');
                                        j$("#translist").hide();
                                        j$( this).html('');
                                        j$("#buttons").html('<input id="reportgenproceed" class="button" type="button" value="Continue" />');
                                        j$( this ).dialog( "close" );
                                    }
                        }

                    });
```

this modal pops up and there is a pdf generated from a servlet but when i click the 'done' button using firefox, firefox crashes

any work around to prevent firefox from crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(j$.browser.mozilla )      j$('<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="'+url+'"></iframe>').dialog({
                                    modal: true,
                                    title: "",
                                    width: 800,
                                    heigth: 600
                          }).dialog("close");
```

my work around code